# DISCORD JS Vote + Coins [top.gg]

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am wanting to integrate the "vote" command of my bot, with the api of top.gg, I want something similar to the command below. this command is the "work" command of my bot, so that you have a base, I would like to modify it so that, when voting for my bot, it delivers "6k of coins" to the user who voted. do you have an explanation of how I can do it? I will leave my code for the work command below, so you can have an idea.

```
async run({ message, args, prefix, author }, t) {
if (!args[0]) {
  User.findOne({ idU: message.author.id }, async (err, user) => {
    let xp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + 1;
    let work = user.work.cooldown;
    let cooldown = 1.44e7;
    let money = Math.ceil(user.work.level * 2 * user.work.coins + 400);
    let nextlevel = user.work.nextLevel * user.work.level;

    if (work !== null && cooldown - (Date.now() - work) > 0) {
      return message.quote(
        `<:daily:842204620977864734> Você deve esperar **${moment
          .duration(cooldown - (Date.now() - work))
          .format("h [hora(s)], m [minuto(s)] e s [segundos]")
          .replace("minsuto(s)", "minuto(s)")}** até poder trabalhar novamente`
      );
    } else {
      if (user.work.exp + xp > nextlevel) {
        message.quote(
          `Parabéns, sua empresa acaba de subir para o level **${
            user.work.level + 1
          }**.`
        );
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { idU: message.author.id },
          {
            $set: {
              "work.cooldown": Date.now(),
              "work.exp": 0,
              coins: user.coins + money,
              "work.level": user.work.level + 1,
            },
          }
        );
      } else {
        message.quote(
          `<:work:846536054399303700><:coins_k:846487970612903976> Você trabalhou com sucesso e obteve **${money.toLocaleString()} coins** e **${xp} de XP**.`
        );
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { idU: message.author.id },
          {
            $set: {
              "work.cooldown": Date.now(),
              "work.exp":
                user.work.exp + xp > nextlevel ? 0 : user.work.exp + xp,
              coins: user.coins + money,
            },
          }
        );
      }
    }
  });
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the user has voted to your bot using`https://top.gg/api/bots/:bot_id/check?userId=userid` endpoint

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch"); // import node-fetch module

const botId = client.user.id; // get the client (bot) id
const uId = message.author.id; // get the author id

const url = `https://top.gg/api/bots/${botId}/check?userId=${uId}`; // api endpoint

fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: { Authorization: "your top.gg bot token" }})
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((json) => {
    var isVoted = JSON.parse(json).voted;

    if (isVoted === 0) {
      return message.channel.send("you haven't voted yet");
    }

    message.channel.send("thank you for voting");
  });
```

Note that this code is not perfect.

You can get your top.gg bot token from `https://top.gg/bot/your-bot-id/webhooks`

Source: https://docs.top.gg/api/bot/#individual-user-vote

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, this was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

By updating the post, I managed to get the desired result, I will leave the code below to others who have the same question!

```
const botId = client.user.id; //
  const uId = message.author.id; // get the author id
  const url = `https://top.gg/api/bots/${botId}/check?userId=${uId}`; // api endpoint
  
  fetch(url, {
        method: "GET", headers: { Authorization: "top.gg token" },
    })
        .then((res) => res.text())
        .then((json) => {
          let isVoted = JSON.parse(json).voted;
    User.findOne({ idU: message.author.id }, async (err, user) => {

    //================= Imports =================//
    let cooldown = 4.68e7;
    let coins = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
    let vote = user.vote;
    let atual = user.coins;
    let time = cooldown - (Date.now() - vote);

            if (isVoted !== null && cooldown - (Date.now() - vote) > 0) {

              return message.channel.send(`**Você já votou em mim hoje!**\n\nVolte em **${moment
                .duration(time)
                .format(
                  "h [Horas] m [Minutos] e s [Segundos]"
                )}**`);
          }

            message.channel.send(`**Vote em mim em:** https://top.gg/bot/762320527637217312/vote **e receba até 5K de coins de forma aleatória!**`);

            await User.findOneAndUpdate(
              { idU: message.author.id },
              { $set: { coins: coins + atual, vote: Date.now() } }
            );
          });
        });
```